# Creating a stack from a circular linked list in order to print the list reversely

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

im solving some stuff for practice for my test. The question in my text book asks me to print the stuff in the circular linked list reversely. so my idea was to create a stack, move the stuff to the stack and then pop it.

Here is what i've done:

```
    public void reversePrint() {
   Stack stack = new Stack();

   Node<E> temp = list;
   do {
   stack.push(temp);
   temp = temp.getNext();
   } while (temp != list);

   while (!stack.empty()) {
   System.out.print(stack.pop());
   }
   }
```

circularlist.java

```
    public class CircularList<E> implements List<E> {

  Node<E> list;
  int size;

  public CircularList() {
    list = new Node(null);
    list.setNext(list);
    size = 0;
  }

  @Override
  public void add(E element) {
    Node<E> newNode = new Node(element);
    newNode.setNext(list.getNext());
    list.setNext(newNode);
    size++;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean remove(E element) {
    Node<E> location = find(element);
    if (location != null) {
      location.setNext(location.getNext().getNext());
      size--;
    }
    return location != null;
  }

  @Override
  public E get(E element) {
    Node<E> location = find(element);
    if (location != null) {
      return (E) location.getNext().getInfo();
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean contains(E element) {
    return find(element) != null;
  }

  @Override
  public int size() {
    return size;
  }

  @Override
  public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new Iterator<E>() {
      Node<E> tmp = list.getNext();

      @Override
      public boolean hasNext() {
        return tmp != list;
      }

      @Override
      public E next() {
        E info = tmp.getInfo();
        tmp = tmp.getNext();
        return info;
      }

      @Override
      public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
      }
    };
  }

  protected Node<E> find(E element) {
    Node<E> tmp = list;
    while (tmp.getNext() != list && !tmp.getNext().getInfo().equals(element)) {
      tmp = tmp.getNext();
    }

    if (tmp.getNext() == list) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return tmp;
    }
```

}

Node.java

```
public class Node<E> {

  E info;
  Node<E> next;

  public Node(E element) {
    info = element;
    next = null;
  }

  public void setInfo(E element) {
    info = element;
  }

  public E getInfo() {
    return info;
  }

  public void setNext(Node<E> next) {
    this.next = next;
  }

  public Node<E> getNext() {
    return next;
  }
}
```

My problem is i cannot use do. I need a different solution instead. Any help?

Comment: *Why* can you not use `do`?

Comment: somehow you need to iterate over the nodes of your list... what are you allowed/required to use then if not `do` ? btw... do you have a `getPrevious()` method in `Node`?

Comment: @A4L no, it's a single circular linked list but i have an iterator designed with next and hasNext methods only.

Comment: @JonSkeet did not take it yet in the course im practicing for.

Comment: @user2272227: So what *can* you use? It sounds like there are many solutions we could present which would be equally invalid...

Comment: @JonSkeet stacks, loops, iteration etc.. i edited main post, see it. Posted my whole code.

Comment: @user2272227: `do` is a loop - but you can't use that for some reason. And `break` is part of looping, but you can't use that. So your comment really doesn't say what you *can* use.

Comment: @JonSkeet i can use for, for each, while loops, no breaks and no parameters for the method.

Comment: Just for curiosity, what `List` interface are you implementing ? this does not seem to be the [java.util.List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html) ... for example `add()` has to return `boolean` and `get()` has to be given a `int` parameter not `E` ...

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have LinkedList written yourself (using the `Node<T>` class).

If the list is doubly linked:

Start from the last element in the list (if you don't store a reference to the tail iterate the nodes until the last is reached) and traverse the list using `getPrevious()` (whatever the opposite of `getNext()` is named).

If the list is single linked:

Instead of using a Stack, you could recursively traverse the list and print the elements when unwinding.

```
public static void <T> reverse(Node<T> current, Node<T> stopAt) {
   Node<T> next = current.getNext();
   if (next != stopAt) {
      reverse(next);
   }
   System.out.println(next.getValue(), stopAt);
}
```

That is simple but not really efficient. If the list holds too many elements you could even run into problems with too deep recursion depth.

*edit : fixed termination condition

Comment: for the method, i cant use parameters. I would just call printReverse() and it would print everything in the list reversely. Circular linked list fyi

Comment: edited the main post. my whole code is now posted.

Comment: You would use this recursive version as a private method inside the `CircularList` class. Inside your printReverse() method you call it and pass the current head of the list as arguments. But as you are not allowed to use do {} while I suspect that you won't be allowed to use recursion. stick with @Jon Skeet's advice (:

Answer (score 1):

If you're "allowed" to use a `while` loop, you can just convert your `do` loop into that, using `break` to get out:

```
while (true) {
    stack.push(temp);
    temp = temp.getNext();
    // If we're back to the beginning, we're done
    if (temp == list) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Or if you can use the `size`, it's even easier:

```
Node<E> temp = list;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    stack.push(temp);
    temp = temp.getNext();
}
```

Comment: jon, yes! but we haven't took break, any other way imstead of break?

Comment: @user2272227: Well I've given you a `for` loop now, but maybe you're not allowed to use that either... You're leaving us guessing at what you're allowed to use, which makes this a pretty pointless question IMO.

Comment: @user2272227: Okay, so the second part of my answer should be okay, right?

Comment: yeh but the second part just adds everything and prints it? i want it to print the list reversely? it doesn't check for anything here?

Comment: public void reversePrinter() {
    
    Stack stack = new Stack();
    Node<E> temp = list;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        stack.push(temp.getInfo());
        temp = temp.getNext();
      }

    while (! stack.empty()) {
      System.out.print(stack.pop());
    }
  }

Comment: that code above prints the last item and rest prints null.

Comment: @user2272227: Then I suggest you haven't populated it properly. You should debug into your code and work out what's going on. You only asked for a way to replace your `do` loop, so that's all I've done. The rest is up to you.

Comment: I think the question is how to write a recursive method, ie not use a loop

Comment: @darrenmc: What makes you say that? I see nothing in the question which implies that. I agree that recursion is another alternative, but the OP already has a plan which should work without recursion.

Comment: @Jon you are right, I misread the question as "print...list recursively" not reversely